# How to remove window decorations in Cinnamon / Muffin?

Tags: 12.04, window-manager, cinnamon

I have installed Cinnamon and Muffin and I *love* them. Finally, I have a working expo! However, I would like to remove all window decorations: I resize and move the windows with alt-mouse, and close them with alt-f4; I have absolutely no need for a title bar. However, I can't seem to find a similar setting for Cinnamon.

Is it possible to get rid of all window decorations in Cinnamon?

Comment: According to `/usr/share/doc/muffin/theme-format.txt.gz`, Muffin themes data are stored in `/usr/share/themes/THEMENAME/metacity-1/`.  You need to edit bits of those XML files, I think.  Alternatively, you could try just deleting those XML files (moving them would be safer!).

Answer (score 5):

Although it is true that you cannot disable window title bars, you can make them so small, that they are hardly visible. As I landed here via google, I post my solution though the thread is old as it might help others. You can edit

```
/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/metacity-1
```

and set all non-zero `value` properties in the `metacity-theme-1.xml` (of course you need sudo, to edit something there. A backup is useful.). Now select under Theme settings -> Other settings -> window borders another theme and reselect `Mint-X`. Now the height of the title bar is determined by the title itself. Chose under Font settings font size 0 for the window title front and the title bar is almost gone.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the Window title bar i.e the window decorations from cinnamon. Cinnamon depends on clutter and uses it to draw the window and decorations.

I believe, The cinnamon window manager `cinnamonwm` get assigned dynamically during runtime.

This is a line from `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/main.js`

```
let cinnamonwm = global.window_manager;
```

So, I believe you cannot do this yet on Cinnamon. *And I'm not going to get the bounty ;*

Comment: No worries, if there is no other opinion and it turns out that I cannot remove the decorations, bounty is yours, Sir :-)

Comment: I think the correct name for Cinnamon's window manager is Muffin.  Muffin is a fork of Mutter; it is the window manager, not the graphics library, that draws decorations.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but you can remove the titlebar with this GNOME tip for maximized windows but you can also adjust the normal window mode settings in the same file.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can use extensions in Ubuntu with Cinnamon like you can in Mint, now you could use "[Cinnamon Maximus](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/29)". Does exactly what you want.

Comment: URL isn't working